# Android TextView and Button alignment

Tags: android, uitableview, textview, android-tablelayout, tablerow

[image]

Please help me out with this! I am new to android, I want to create a two text view and one button in the same Table row with three things should be aligned centred both horizontally and vertically. Here is my code it's working but there is no proper alignment and I added the snapshot of my window which doesn't align properly.

```
 <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/exp_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
<TableRow>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_margin="1dp" />
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/mEdttxt1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
            android:text=""
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_span="4"
            />
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/exp_Nxt"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"/>
</TableRow>
```

Help Me!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LinearLayout inside your TableRow.

Try this code:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/exp_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_margin="1dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mEdttxt1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
            android:text=""
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_span="4"/>
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/exp_Nxt"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Raka pls check it out i uploaded my screen shot.

Comment: Abdul, where is it? I can't see it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381801/android-textview-and-button-alignment/21382186?noredirect=1#comment32288686_21382186

Comment: Able to see ,is t visible raka?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<TableLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >
  <TableRow >
         <TextView

            android:id="@+id/exp_text1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yourstring"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:layout_margin="1dp" />
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/mEdttxt1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/exp_Nxt"

            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Hi subha,thanks for your answer but its not working.Actually tablerow is my seprate xml and im inflating this xml by table layout xml

Comment: Pls chek it out i have uploaded my screenshot'